# Sending bash result to printer

Tags: bash

I have a bash script :

```
 for i in `grep -E -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' log.txt | uniq`
 do
     loc=`geoiplookup $i`    
     if [ "$loc" == "GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States" ]; then 
         echo $i
     fi
 done
```

I want to sent this result to printer. how i can do this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find printers using `lpstat -a`, then pass the output of your script to lp:

```
$ ./my_script.sh | lp -d [PRINTER]
```

Comment: i want sending to printer in script. do this work on script

Answer (score 1):

@JoshJolly's answer covers the essentials, but just in case you wanted to **print output from select commands from within the script itself**:

Simply pipe the command of interest to `lp`.

To send your command to the default printer, try:

```
for i in `grep -E -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' log.txt | uniq`
do
   loc=`geoiplookup $i`    
   if [ "$loc" == "GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States" ]; then 
       echo $i
   fi
done | lp
```